# Angularjs autocomplete json with and without http

Tags: php, json, angularjs, autocomplete

In my code i use angular (material) autocomplete and i need to get data from external php file.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="search_interest" layout="column">
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column">

      <md-autocomplete 
        md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
        md-search-text="searchText" 
        md-items="item in getInterest1(searchText)" 
        md-item-text="item.name" 
        placeholder="Search for a vegetable">
        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}} :: {{item.type}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>

  </div>
```

When i return an "handmade" JSON, autocomplete works well:

```
//RETURN: results [{"name":"Broccoli","type":"Brassica"}]
    $scope.getInterest1 = function() {
      var results = [
        {
          'name': 'Broccoli',
          'type': 'Brassica'
        }];
        console.log('results', JSON.stringify(results));
        return results;
        };
```

But when i call the same JSON using $http.get it doesn't show results in autocomplete and nothing happends.

```
//RETURN: results [{"name":"Broccoli","type":"Brassica"}]
    $scope.getInterest2 = function() {
      $http.get("../inc/users/search_interest.php?query=" + $scope.searchText)
        .success(function(results) {
          //$scope.interest = results;
          console.log('results', JSON.stringify(results));
          return results.data;
        });
    };
```

But i can see in console that results are equals.

In my php file (which is called by $http.get) i return JSON with json-encode:

```
$row_set = array('name' => 'Broccoli', 'type'=> 'Brassica');
echo json_encode(array($row_set));
```

Maybe php json_encode return a bad formed json?

Thanks

Comment: `echo json_encode($row_set);` is enough.

Comment: Yes i know is enough, but let me explain that i used as shown in my code above because else i get results {"name":"Broccoli","type":"Brassica"} in console (so without [ ]). it was a try. But also echo json_encode($row_set); autocomplete not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Just resolved my issue using promise.
In controller i declared $q

```
function($scope, $http, $q)
{
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.selectedItem = undefined;
    $scope.selectedInterest = [];

    var deferred = $q.defer();
```

In function i used $q:

```
$scope.getInterest2 = function() {
      $http.get("../inc/users/search_interest.php?query=" + $scope.searchText)
        .success(function(results) {
          //$scope.interest = results;
          console.log('results', JSON.stringify(results));
          alert(results.name);
          deferred.resolve(results);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Thanks!